# Count rows and columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I go about defining a fuctions in counting the number of rows and columns in a list of lists? For example group1 would be 1 row with 6 columns.

```
group1  =   [['.',  'A',    'A',    '.',    '.',    '.']]

def num_rows(group):

def num_columns(group):
```

Comment: Your description says you want to count the rows *and* columns, yet your function is named `num_rows`.

Comment: I will be making two defined functions, my bad. Will add it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check the first index:

```
def num_rows(group):
    return len(group)

def num_columns(group):
    return len(group[0])
```

Take in mind this will raise an `IndexError` exception if there's no rows.

Answer (score 1):

he number of rows is the number of elements in the main list, and the number of columns is the number of elements in one of the elements. `len()` returns the number of elements in a list.

```
rows = len(group1)
columns = len(group1[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

try using print(group1.shape), works for me